# ODE with non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following ODE:

$(x^2-4)y^{(6)}+x^3y'''+9y=0$

Assume $y(0)=c_0,y'(0)=c_1,...,y^{(5)}(0)=c_5$. Then applying Laplace transform to the ODE gives
\begin{multline}
(-4s^6+30s^4+3)L(y)+(12s^5-18s)L'(y)+(s^6-3s^2)L''(y)-s^3L'''(y)\\+(4s^5-20s^3)c_0+(4s^4-12s^2)c_1\\+(4s^3-6s)c_2+(4s^2-2)c_3+4sc_4+c_5=0.
\end{multline}
However taking the inverse Laplace transform seems to be quite tedious: computing $L^{-1}(\dfrac1{4s^6-30s^4-3}) $ by splitting the argument into partial fractions form requires solving a cubic equation with no rational root.

If I consider first the ODE $y^{(6)}+y'''+9y=0$, its characteristic equation is $\mu^6+\mu^3+9=0\implies\mu^3=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-35}}{2}$ or $\mu^3=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{-35}}{2}$. Solving for the cube roots of those seems to be a tedious process of solving cubic equations. Say the real cube roots of the previous values for $\mu^3$ are $\mu_1, \mu_2$, then the roots of the characteristic equation are $\mu_1,\mu_1\omega,\mu_1\omega^2,\mu_2,\mu_2\omega,\mu_2\omega^2$ where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$. So $e^{\mu_1},e^{\mu_2},e^{\mu_1}\cos(2\pi /3),e^{\mu_2}\cos(2\pi /3),e^{\mu_1}\sin(2\pi /3),e^{\mu_2}\sin(2\pi /3)$ forms a basis for the solution space to $y^{(6)}+y'''+9y=0$. However it isn't clear to me how this relates to the solution of the original ODE.

Another method I tried is to let $u=y'''$, so the original ODE becomes $u'+\dfrac{x^3}{x^2-4}u+9\dfrac{y(x)}{x^2-4}=0$. The solution to its homogenous part is $\dfrac {ce^{-x^2/2}}{(x^2-4)^2}$. By variation of parameters, we have $c'(x)\dfrac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x^2-4}+c(x)\dfrac{2xe^{-x^2/2}}{x^2-4}=-9y(x)\implies c'(x)+2xc(x)=-9(x^2-4)e^{x^2/2}y(x)$. Again, $c(x)=b(x)e^{-x^2}\implies b'(x)=-9(x^2-4)e^{3x^2/2}y(x)$.

Is there anything I could do to facilitate finding the solution to the original ODE with any of  these methods I've tried? Or is there a better way I haven't thought of, save for perhaps power series method?

Comment: How did you get rid of the derivatives of the Laplace transform resulting from the coefficients $x^2y^{(6)}(x)$ and $x^3y'''(x)$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I had used $L(-tf(t))(s)=\dfrac{d}{ds}L(f(t))$, and the formula for Laplace transform of higher order derivatives but maybe I did make some mistakes in my calculations by accident?

Comment: Yes, so where did these derivatives end up? There should be an $F''(s)$ and $F'''(s)$ where $F(s)=L\{t\mapsto f(t)\}(s)$.

Comment: It's the $L(y)$ term, isn't it?

Comment: Wait... the L(y) term is dependent on s, oops I forgot